# Saving Matplotlib figure in SVG using pixels

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

When I save my Matplotlib figure with `savefig('filename.svg')` the resulting SVG file uses pts for units:

```
<svg height="324pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 432 324" width="432pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

How can I configure Matplotlib to output its SVG file in pixels instead?

Comment: SVG is a [vector format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) rather than a [raster format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics). It consists of a set of arbitrarily scalable paths defined by control points, rather than a fixed array of pixel values, so it makes no sense to use pixels as a unit of size.

Comment: @ali_m I appreciate that SVG is a vector format but that doesn't mean that pixels can't be used in setting up an image at an initial scale (of course, the size that the image appears on the screen will then be device dependent). In fact, pixels are the default unit of none is specified. E.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html

Comment: Fair enough - I did not realise that pixel-valued units were part of the SVG standard. In any case, I'm pretty sure that matplotlib doesn't support any units other than points - [the `pt` unit seems to be hard-coded into the `RendererSVG` class](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_svg.py#L291-L297). I suppose you could open a feature request. For the time being, the simplest work-around would probably be to directly edit the XML after it is written.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I should have looked at the source myself. In my case, I'm adding extra SVG elements after Matplotlib renders and it's for a web page, so I think I'll do what you suggest and edit by hand.